# Константные операторы C++, почему и зачем?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.
В C++ есть понятие функтора и предиката.
Когда я эти понятия изучал, я столкнулся с константными операторами.

Есть строка типа:

```
int operator()(int arg) const
```

И строка типа:

```
int operator()(int arg)
```

Обе эти строки просто объявляют оператор, который для каждого arg возвращает arg + 1.

Для строки `transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), Comp());` оба объявления работают одинаково хорошо. Всё компилируется и все элементы в векторе и правда увеличиваются на 1

Так в чём же разница между обьявлением с const, и без него?

Comment: константные операторы нужны по той же причине, что и любые другие константные методы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Константные операторы, и вообще константные функции, нужны чтобы их можно было вызвать у константного объекта, через константную ссылку или указатель на объект.
Например для `const Comp c;` или `const Comp&`.